# NSTimer: время таймера в int

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день. Такой вопрос есть. Мне нужно сделать задержку на кнопку. (Если до 3х сек выполнить одно действие, больше 3х сек другое) Ставлю `NSTimer`. Когда отпускаю кнопу, он завершается. Там где приходит ответ от таймера и перед тем как я его обнуляю мне нужен цикл. Но... одна проблемка. Как мне отследить сколько времени была нажата кнопка?

```
 - (IBAction)mainButtonPut:(id)sender {

      self.toTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(mainButtonOutput:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    - (IBAction)mainButtonOutput:(id)sender {

        if ([toTimer isValid]) {

            [toTimer invalidate];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам не нужно точно знать, сколько секунд была нажата кнопка, а достаточно просто знать дольше или меньше трех секунд, то попробуйте так:

Создайте два разных экшна - на нажатие кнопки и на отпускание (Touch Down и Touch Up Inside эвенты).

```
- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender
{
    self.toTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3f target:self selector:@selector(fire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)fire
{
    longPress = YES;
}

- (IBAction)touchUpInside:(id)sender
{
    if (longPress == YES)
        [self doSmth];
    else
        [self doSmthElse];

    longPress = NO;
    [self.toTimer invalidate];
    self.toTimer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А че проще нельзя?
Нажал на кнопку сохранил

```
NSDate *onPress=[NSDate date];
```

Отпустил

```
if ([date earlierDate:[NSDate date]]) {

            }
```

еще есть laterDate

**UPD:** Вот еще можно `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` заюзать. Событие вызывается если тап пальцем долго держится на объекте.

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите именно таймер, то разместите две кнопки строго одна поверх другой и каждую назначьте на соответствующие `action`'ы. По таймеру задавайте кнопке

```
button.alpha = 0; 
button.hidden = YES;
```

а другой кнопке соответственно - 1 и NO